# Derserialising nested JObject's into Dictionary<string,string> in JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialise some data that looks like:

```
{
   "item1":"value1",
   "item2":2,
   "item3":true,
   "item4":{
       "subItem1":"subValue1",
       "subItem2":"subValue2",
   }
}
```

In C# I'd like the deserialised object to be an instance of something like:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

Where the actual type of each Value object is either: string, double, boolean or `Dictionary<string,string>`

I can trivially use a statement like:

```
JSONConvert.Deserialise<Dictionary<string,object>>(text);
```

but that gives me Value objects of types: string, double, boolean or `JObject`

I'm interested in working out how to route the unknown `JObject`'s into `Dictionary<string, string>` objects.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have users sending me JSON in whatever format they'd like to. I'd use dynamic, but I have to serialize their request for MSMQ and dynamics aren't serializable, so I'd really like the object and every property and sub-property to be a Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deserializing to a dictionary you can make use of `dynamic`

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
Console.WriteLine(json.item1);
Console.WriteLine(json.item4.subItem1);
```

JObject also implements IDictionary so you can also use it as

```
var jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
Console.WriteLine(jobj["item4"]["subItem1"]);
```

Comment: Sorry - can't be done... as I'm also cross-platform, including on MonoTouch!

Comment: Interesting idea - playing with it (this is in the middle of lots of reflection code... so being careful...)

Comment: Close - but not quite... `JObject` doesn't actually seem to support `IDictionary` - instead it supports `IDictionary<string, JToken>` - which sadly doesn't inherit from `IDictionary`... I'm trying to avoid having JObject or JToken (or any JSON.Net specific code) in the model and service code - trying to contain it in the deserialiser.

Comment: @Stuart JToken, Jproperty supports explicit conversions, you can use as `(int)jobj["item4"]["subItem1"]` or `(DateTime)jobj["item4"]["dateItem1"]`

Comment: Thanks - but I need a conversion really - what you suggest would work if I could rewrite lots of other code... but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Stuart I guess you wouldn't want to use `.ToString()` either.